# Antonym to 'Assign'

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

Suppose we have users and operators.  Some users are assigned to certain operators.  What should I call a procedure of removing an assignment, so an operator no longer works with a user or group of users?
What are some antonyms for *assign*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about "dissociate" or "deallocate"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more associate/dissociate, allocate/deallocate?

Comment: I vote for unassigning! Language is flexible :)

Answer (score 11):

There is some question about whether it is a real word, but I have seen and occasionally used "deassign."

Comment: I also saw 'unassign', but it doesn't sound well.

Comment: I agree, unassign doesn't sound quite right. A variable can be unassigned, but I don't think this should be used as an active verb.

Answer (score 8):

If you "**assign**" users to an operator, you may "**remove**" users from the operator.

Comment: It's opposite, operators are being assigned to groups of users. So if i can 'assign operator to group', then i can't say that i'm 'removing operator from group' because group consists of users, not operators.

Answer (score 2):

[*Divest*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divest) comes to my mind:

> (transitive) To strip, deprive, or dispossess (someone) of something (such as a right, passion, privilege, or prejudice).
>
> > You shall never divest me of my right to free speech.

So if the original procedure is:

> Assign users to an operator.

The antonym is:

> Divest an operator of users.

Comment: Wikitionary says it's an archaic word. I think many of my colleagues don't have it in their vocabulary, I also hear it for the first time. Is there a more widespread word?

Comment: It's archaic for the meaning of "undress", not for the meaning we're talking about here.

Comment: @RiMMER You completely missed the point. Nobody knows what the word _divest_ means, and nobody uses it, so it is a poor choice even if you think it's \*technically\* correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can *revoke* a task that has been allocated to someone

Comment: Maybe i'm just carping, but _revoke_ is more of use with privilegies. And i have a group of users being supported by operator.

Answer (score 0):

How about **"dismiss"** ? 
one of the word's definitions is  - "discharge from employment or office" which fits quite perfectly as far as I can see. 
"assign a doctor" / "dismiss doctor" 
at least one more option to the mentioned above )))

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **absign**.

Why? Due to the morphology of **assign**:

> Middle English, from Anglo-French assigner, from Latin assignare, from ad- + signare to mark, from signum mark, sign

The opposite of "ad" in Latin is "ab", and it's used in words such as "abstain", "absolve", "abdicate" etc. in English. So, replacing "ad" with "ab" gets you "absign".

Why not? I've not heard anybody else use it.

Comment: Well, morphology of a word is not exactly a well-known thing. Especially  for non-native speakers whose primary interest is English, not Latin or any other related language. A fact that you didn't hear anyone using it means it's not common for average person's active vocabulary. In my case I had to find a well-known word since it was intended for use in software code. A good code should be self-describing. It won't be if a person reading will have to look refer  to a dictionary to understand function's name.

Comment: And "absign" is not in any of my dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

If the user is moved to a different operator, I would go for "reassigned", which carries the proper connotations, I feel.

Comment: No, it's just link between them being removed

Answer (score -3):

*Resign* is a proper answer to your question.

Comment: No, it is not. I *assign* someone else the task. I don't *resign* someone else the task.